# What is the current state of Squeeze-suit development, as distinguished from gas-pressurized models?

Tags: spacesuits

[This](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/moon-mars/a2050/4220822/) ten-year-old article on a squeezesuit concept estimates that it is ten years from completion.

Ten years have passed, and this article is still the #1 hit on Google, with a couple of other speculative science-fiction-oriented results.

Has any significant progress been made with this technology? Is this particular MIT research project still alive?

[image: Squeezesuit]

Comment: Since Dava Newman became a NASA bureaucrat, very little.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about mechanical-counter-pressure (MCP) suits.

Comment: Yeah, and it seems like a good summary of the technical problems facing the suit, but I'm asking what the state of the solutions to those problems are. I think the answer may be that it's dead in the water, but I'd prefer to see an answer that said "yeah, this project ended in 2017", or "it's been picked up by space startup Y", or something more definitive.

Comment: Good point. Withdrawing duplicate vote.  I think you're right though, it's dead in the water.

Comment: related: [What ever happened with that pressure suit design based on elastic tension in contact with skin?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27544/12102) Would you consider "It looks like the concept never really went away, and that such a suit is still in active development." a sufficient answer, or are there some additional details you'd like to ask about. I clicked "accept" there, but I have a hunch there's more to be told.

Comment: If the squeeze pressure of the suit would be as high as neccessary, the suit could not be worn without a pressurized helmet. The image is a proof that the squeeze pressure is low, inhalation would be impossible otherwise.

Comment: But Dava Newman left NASA two years ago. Did she join MIT again and continued research of the suit?

Comment: @Uwe - yeah, the other question basically has an unsupported assertion that it's still going on - I have strong doubts that this is the case.

Comment: I've reached out to Dava Newman on Twitter...maybe we'll a definitive answer.